# Mock extensions function inside Companion Object

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockk, extension-function

I have a class (class A) to which I define an extension function (A.extension()) inside a companion object of another class (class B) for a matter of organization.

On my tests I need:

- To use a real class A instance .
- To mock A.extension().
- To use a mock instance of class B.

Using MockK-library I am not being able to mock that extension function successfully.
I've tried:

```
        mockkObject(B.Companion) {
            every { any<A>().extension() } returns whatIneed
        }
```

result: Tries to run the unmocked version of the extension function.

```
        mockkStatic(path.to.B.CompanionKt)
            every { any<A>().extension() } returns whatIneed
```

Result: It does not find the Companion Object.

```
        mockkStatic(A::extension) {
            every { any<A>().extension() } returns whatIneed
        }
```

Result: Compile error -> 'extension' is a member and an extension at the same time. References to such elements are not allowed.

Am I missing something regarding how to mock this ?
Am I doing something wrong in terms of code structuring that prevents this mocking to be possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `A.extension()` used anywhere other than class B itself?

Comment: Yes, it is there really just for organization purposes because B is a repository class and A.extension() is basically syntatic sugar to for a database operation on instances of A.

Comment: Then why add such an extension in class B? If there are other classes calling it, why not add it to class A for example?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an impossible thing. I have tried this severally and it does not work.

Comment: I also had no success. Ended up moving the functions out of the companion object into a regular object/file.

Comment: How about in the case where the function in main activity needs to be statically defined. How can i go about it

Comment: I don't know much about android development since I use Kotlin for micro-service development. That being said, you can either place the function in a regular object instead of a companion object, and that makes it mockable. 
Or, if outside any formally defined scope, like outside the "class/activity" brackets, which also makes it static. 
Both ways make it mockable via mockStatic.